# Can't find system.out.println()

Tags: intellij-idea

I created a project, it asked me to select JDK version and finish.

I couldn't find `system` namespace in autocomplete.

I typed it manually but IDEA told me that `system` doesn't exist.

Comment: Just type `sout` and TAB.

Comment: @vlio20 really provided the way to go, but do remember to specify an applicable context (for example Java and/or Groovy). Unless you do that, it will not work (personal experience!)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

It's `System` (with a cap)

Some very useful shortcuts:

```
soutm (+TAB) ==> System.out.println("Class.And.Method.Name")
soutv (+TAB) ==> System.out.println("Last variable used = " + value);
sout (+TAB) ==> System.out.println();
```

I really love IntelliJ. Glad I moved to it from Eclipse a couple of years ago ;)

Comment: Oh, so the intellisense is case sensitive ? It is a drawback compared to eclipse.

Comment: But your objects are case sensitive, so it kind of makes sense... I used Eclipse for 6 years before I accepted to try IntelliJ for a while (that was in 2008). 3 days later, I was convinced. Anyway, to each his own, Eclipse is great too :)

Comment: I prefer case insensitive autocompletion so it's a drawback to me. It would be great if there is a option to change that behaviour.

Comment: Well I like it the way it is, it allows camelCase autocompletion. If you type "PrM", it would find and prioritise in the list "ProjectManager" for example.

Comment: Anyway, I found it : http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/editor-code-completion.html. @Guillaume, you also can do camelCase autocompletion with case insensitive autocompletion, I just tested it.

Comment: @JatSing thanks so much this is amazing. Case sensitivity makes no sense with auto-complete, instead it should just prioritize matching case objects first. Then you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Terrific. However, where did you find the shortcut in the first place, @Guillaume?

Comment: Don't really remember... From colleagues who knew them, I suppose :)

Comment: Is there a similar autocomplete feature for String.format as for sout, soutm, soutv?

Comment: Another fancy shorcut is `soutp` which prints all parameter in the method.

Comment: @JatSing The link jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/editor-code-completion.html is broken.

Answer (score 36):

Just type `sout`.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int data = 1;
    System.out.println(); ===>sout 
    System.out.println("Main.main"); ===>soutm 
    System.out.println("args = [" + args + "]"); ===>soutp 
    System.out.println("data = " + data); ===>soutv 
}
```

}

`sout` - just print System.out.println()

`soutm` - added Class name & method name

`soutp` - added parameter

`soutv` - added last variable name

Answer (score 14):

We can change the auto complete settings to to **ignore case**. Go to:

```
File -> Settings... -> IDE Settings -> Editor -> Code Completion
```

and change **'Case sensitive completion'** to **'None'**.

Comment: For 2016 version, the settings is on `File > Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion > Case Sensitive Completion > None`

Answer (score 12):

I came from eclipse and was using the `syso` shortcut, so I have just added it to my live template. Here is a templete:

`System.out.println($END$);`

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Don't forget to add Java as applicable context (at the bottom of the window).
Now it will appear as a hint while you typing `syso` here is a screenshot:
[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen because user has not created any main function or trying to test this directly in class without any function

Comment: This should have been a comment, rather than an answer.