# Intellij Editor Code Completion

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently moved to Intellij from Eclipse. I am using Intellij 2017.1.5 version on MacOS X 10.12.5 with Eclipse Mac OS key map.

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8492230/785523) answer is there a place I can view all the code completions for Intellij?

Comment: Are you looking for [this documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html)?

Comment: I am looking for the all the completions like `sout(+TAB)` should complete `System.out.print`. Please refer the link I posted in my question.

Comment: You can find all the live templates here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/live-templates-2.html.

Comment: As mentioned in your link I found the templates under `IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Editor | Live Templates` in Mac OS X. Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the predefined Live Templates here: `File` | `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `Live Templates`.

[See the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/live-templates-2.html) for more details.